# sparkR sql() returns string

Tags: r, parquet, sparkr

We have `parquet` data saved on a server and I am trying to use `SparkR` `sql()` function in the following ways

```
df <- sql("SELECT * FROM parquet.`<path to parquet file`")
head(df)
show(df) # returns "<SQL> SELECT * FROM parquet.`<path to parquet file`"
```

and

```
createOrReplaceTempView(df, "table")
df2 <- sql("SELECT * FROM table")
show(df2) # returns "<SQL> SELECT * FROM table"
```

In both cases what I get is the sql query in a string format instead of the spark dataframe. Does anyone have any idea why this happens and why I don't get the dataframe?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

This was a very silly problem. The solution is to just use the full name of the method

```
SparkR::sql(...)
```

instead of the short name. Apparently the function `sql` is masked.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the `show` statement use `showDF()`...or, `View(head(df2, num=20L))`

Answer (score 0):

[show](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/show.html) method documentation in sparkR states that if eager evaluation is not enabled it returns the class and type information of the Spark object. so you should use [showDF](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/showDF.html) instead.

besides that, apparently, the `sql` method is masked in `R` and you should call it with explicit package deceleration. like this:

```
df <- SparkR::sql("select 1")
showDF(df)
```

Comment: The `sql` function is only masked if *you* masked it. That is, if you defined your own `sql` function, or attached a package which does.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I use databricks runtime and I think they may have some packages preinstalled that cause this.